# How to override inline css coming from js

Tags: jquery, html, css

```
<div class="ui-slider-range ui-widget-header" style="left: 16.67824878387769%; width: 70.8825573314802%; "><p>4:00am  9:00pm</p></div>
```

The entire div is coming through jquery .Unfortunately i dont have the access to  js .I need to remove left and width using css ,Is it possible ?

Comment: Why not reset the css as `.ui-slider-range.ui-widget-header {left:0!important;width:100%!important;}`

Comment: I'm wondering why you'd need to override the styles of an internal part of the a jqueryUI widget? What's gone wrong with the widget's layout that you need to override it? Note: If you're trying to change the actual value of the slider widget, changing the CSS is not the way to do it.

Comment: @Spudley  :yea you are absolutely right ,but by adjusting  the left and width using css my entire problem will solve .

Comment: @prash - Sorry, but I guarantee you that hacking the left and width using CSS will **not** solve the problem. I've posted a fuller version of my comment as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm wondering why you'd need to override the styles of an internal part of the a jqueryUI widget? What's gone wrong with the widget's layout that you need to override it?

Note: If you're trying to change the actual value of the slider widget, changing the CSS is not the way to do it -- Yes, the other answers given here will cause the element to drop its width and left attributes, but it won't change the widget's slider marker values, and as soon as the user touches the widget again, it'll reappear.

To be clear: What you're trying to do is hack a widget, in a way that simply won't work.

If you want to set the widget to have the slider at zero, you need to do it via Javascript, not CSS. Please see the jQueryUI manual -- http://api.jqueryui.com/slider/

I suspect you need something like this:

```
 $(".selector").slider( "values", 0, 0 );
 $(".selector").slider( "values", 1, 0 );
```

where '.selector' is the reference for the main element that contains the slider (not a selector for individual bits of the widget generated by jqueryUI).

I hope that helps.

Answer (score 3):

If you have access only to css file use [!important](http://www.electrictoolbox.com/using-important-css/):

```
.ui-slider-range, 
.ui-widget-header {
    width: 100px !imporant;
    left: 0 !important;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use jQuery function css to change the [**css**](http://api.jquery.com/css/) properties.

```
$(function(){
     $('.ui-slider-range.ui-widget-header').css('left', '');
     $('.ui-slider-range.ui-widget-header').css('width', '');
});
```

*If you do not have access to js still you can add your script to change the already generated html elements.*

Comment: Its fine, but user wants a CSS solution.

Answer (score 2):

Or you cand try adding !important at your css declaration.
eg. width:100% !important;

Answer (score 2):

use this `!important`:

```
.yourCssClass{
    height:0px !important;
 }
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TPL3f/